# UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (713, 6). Other element would receive the click: <div class="container">...</div>

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am getting really weird error. In my test, I first navigate to angularjs.org. Then I sendKeys() to an input field called "JavaScript Projects" which has filters in it. After that I click a checkbox and mark a todo item as Done. However, on doing this, it get the error,

> UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (713, 6). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)

If I reverse the order of my execution above, no error occurs.

Here is my Code

```
var util = require ('util');
describe ("Page object text", function() {
var homepage = require('../pages/angularjs_page.js');
it ("Should mark an item done", function() {
    homepage.get();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    homepage.searchText('jquery');
    homepage.markDoneTodo(0);
});  
});
```

Here is the page object code:

```
var angularjs_page = function() {
    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
    };
    this.markDoneTodo = function(index) {
        element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'))
            .get(index)
                .element(by.model('todo.done'))
                    .click();
    };
    this.searchText = function(txt) {
        element(by.model('projectList.search')).sendKeys(txt);
    };
};
module.exports = new angularjs_page();
```

Maximizing the browser window did not work. Sleep() does not seem to be causing this issue. Inserting a sendKey() method in between works fine.

```
browser.sleep(2000);
    homepage.searchText('jquery');
    homepage.enterName("Hello World");
    homepage.markDoneTodo(0);
```

So, what is wrong with executing searchText() and markDoneTodo() methods in sequence?

**Problem Found**
Turns out that the static top navigation menu bar was overlapping the checkboxes. Is scrolling the best way to solve it, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using scroll solved the problem.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)');
```